# Cypress : Code goes to infinite loop , unable to break the loop when condition is met

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

When I get started the 1st if condition works fine but when $initialVal.text() changes to failed or finished my script goes in infinite loop.

Using below code:

```
let maxCount = 1000;
for(let i = 0; i< maxCount; i++){
cy.get('locator').each(($initialVal, index, list) => {
  expect(index).to.be.greaterThan(-1);
  if ($initialVal.text() == 'started')
    cy.get("locator").type({'enter'});
  else if ($initialVal.text() == 'failed')
     cy.log("Status is " + $initialVal.text());
    **//here I need to break the loop**
  else {
     cy.log("Status is " + $initialVal.text());
  }
}
```

I am expecting a solution where if the status is Started it should perform the action and if its failed or something else it should perform different action and then break the loop.

Comment: You asked the same question earlier today

Comment: actually there were few incorrect thing and it was closed so I asked new one with updated requirement.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop a `for` loop inside a Cypress command because of the asynchronous execution.
But you can just skip the iterations:

```js
    let stop = false;
    let maxCount = 1000;
    for (let i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
      cy.then(() => {
        if (!stop) {
          cy.get('locator').each(($initialVal, index, list) => {
            expect(index).to.be.greaterThan(-1);
            if ($initialVal.text() == 'started')
              cy.get('locator').type({ 'enter' });
            else if ($initialVal.text() == 'failed') {
              cy.log('Status is ' + $initialVal.text());
              stop = true;
            } else cy.log('Status is ' + $initialVal.text());
          });
        }
      })
    }
```